# Reference counting in a collection

Tags: c++, multithreading, collections, stl, reference-counting

Let's have a collection of objects (say string is type of collection). I want each element of collection to have a reference count. So, on *Add-Usage* it should increment count for this given element.

```
coll.AddUsage("SomeElement"); // Type doesn't matter - but should increase count
```

On, *Release-Usage*, it should decrement the reference count for given element, and if count reaches `0`, then it should remove the element from collection.

It is not important if `AddUsage` will allocate element (and set reference-count to `1`), or would fail altogether (since element didn't exist). Important thing is `RemoveUsage`, which should remove given element (object) from collection.

I thought of using `vector` of a `pair` (or a custom struct), or using any kind of `map`/`multimap`. There exists no existing class in C++ library (may be out of thread-support library, one atomic classes, shared-pointer classes etc).

**Question:**

So, my question is how to implement such idea, using existing C++ library? It should be thread safe. Yes, C++11/14 is perfectly okay for me. If good idea is there, I would probably craft it on top of templates.

Comment: You forgot to ask the question...

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Can't you just use a collection of `shared_ptr`s?

Comment: @ravi, I modified the post. I assumed that people would assume my question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you ask for a data structure to implement your reference-counting collection...

Use a `map<K,V>` with K as the type of collection elements (in your example string) and V a type to keep track of meta-information about the element (e.g. reference count). The simplest case is when V is `int`.

Then, `AddUsage` is simple, just do `refMap[value]++`. For RemoveUsage just do a `refMap[value]--`, then check if the counter hit zero and remove the value from the map.

You need to add error handling too, since `AddUsage` / `RemoveUsage` may be 
called with an object which is not in the map (not added to the collection)

EDIT: You tagged your question with "multithreading", so you probably want to have a mutex of some sort which guards the concurrent access to `refMap`.

Comment: Yes, this one mostly makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

You could implement something similar to `shared_ptr` class but extending it to hold collection of objects.

Like you could design a class with `map/multimap` as its data member. Key would be your object and value be your reference count.As far as interface is concerned just expose two methods:-

```
AddUsage(Object);
RemoveUsage(Object);
```

In your AddUsage method you would first check if element already exists in map.If yes then only increment the count. Likewise you would handle RemoveUsage.Object would be deleted from map if its reference count reaches zero.

This is just my opinion. Please let me know if there are any bottlenecks in this implementation.

Comment: Yes, I need something similar to `shared_ptr` only (that should be question). But I want to hold objects, not pointers.

Comment: You can hold objects in that map if you want to...I don't know any standard structure which could be used for this purpose...

Answer (score -3):

You can use static member(integer) variable in the structure or class. Increment or decrement whereever you want. Remove the element if the value is zero.

Comment: No, static member is definitely wrong since the OP is trying to count the references to a single instance.

Comment: It's a collection of object, and each object need to have reference count.